# Unable to download the .xls file from chrome browser using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Able to download the file .xls in Firefox browser using below script code.

```
window.open(/api/v1/test/id);
```

Able to download pdf,image extensions like jpg,jpeg etc.. Unable to download the .xls file in chrome browser using above script.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What happens in Chrome when you try to download the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144062/display-xls-file-data-in-a-browser-as-a-web-content

Comment: It's downloading as zip file with different format

Comment: Please check in your machine whether default zip format is used? . Using in windows or linux env?

Comment: working on linux env. Where I have to check zip format is used as default?

Comment: Can u please share the full code snippet?

Comment: Using window.open(url) for opening the .xls file in new window.

Comment: url is nothing but server api

Comment: @newtonash , did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the Content-Type correctly at the server side.

For example, in Node for Excel 2007 and above .xlsx files

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
```

Chrome is *probably* interpreting your content as application/zip

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/zip"});
```

Here is an example of an xlsx being served up in Chrome when accessing localhost:1215

```
  var http = require("http");
  fileSystem = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');
  var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '1775IronHorse.xlsx');
  var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);
  response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-    officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                            'Content-Length': stat.size
                            });
  var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
  readStream.pipe(response);
});

server.listen(1215);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

The file downloads correctly as an xlsx.

When I remove the Content-Type Header the file is interpreted as zip file by Chrome. Therefore, the solution is to add the Content-Type Header.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files)